# flutter + firebase passwordless email login - dynamic link data returns null

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to implement passwordless email login on my app. 
After the link has been clicked on, the app returns from the background but the dynamic link is null.

This is how I send the mail (with the right values for my app of course):

```
user.sendSignInWithEmailLink(
      email: _email,
      androidInstallIfNotAvailable: true,
      iOSBundleID: "com.company.appname",
      androidMinimumVersion: "16",
      androidPackageName: "com.company.appname",
      url: "https://appname.page.link/email",
      handleCodeInApp: true);
```

I also added the intent as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

           <data android:host="appname.page.link" android:scheme="http"/>
           <data android:host="appname.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Tried different variations with the intent, and non helped, including writing the firebase 
project url as the host like: `project-name.firebaseapp.com`

The data still comes back empty.

Any thoughts? am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the `firebase_dynamic_links` package to the latest version (0.5.0+9),
 while using the configuration below and it starts working.

**Sending sign-in link configuration:**

```
firebaseAuth.sendSignInWithEmailLink(
        email: email,
        url: "https://mydemoapp.page.link/email",
        androidInstallIfNotAvailable: true,
        androidMinimumVersion: '21',
        androidPackageName: 'com.example.mydemoapp'
        handleCodeInApp: true,
        iOSBundleID: 'com.example.mydemoapp');
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** intent-filter configuration:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:host="mydemoapp.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:host="mydemoapp.page.link" android:scheme="http"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

**Getting a dynamic link in Flutter.**

The example comes form from https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links

If your app did not open from a dynamic link, `getInitialLink()` will **return null**. That's the reason why you have to `FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink` implemented in case the app is already opened.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Dynamic Links Example',
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/': (BuildContext context) => MyHomeWidget(), // Default home route
      '/helloworld': (BuildContext context) => MyHelloWorldWidget(),
    },
  ));
}

class MyHomeWidgetState extends State<MyHomeWidget> {
  .
  .
  .
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.initDynamicLinks();
  }

  void initDynamicLinks() async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;

    if (deepLink != null) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
    }

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
      onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
        final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

        if (deepLink != null) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
        }
      },
      onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
        print('onLinkError');
        print(e.message);
      }
    );
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

The `mydemoapp.page.link` must be added to **Authorized domains** in Firebase console

Comment: solved. it was the FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink that did the trick. afterwards just sent the deepLink.toString() to signInWithEmailAndLink

Answer (score 0):

Is it `appname.page.link` or `appname.page.link/email` you have to specify only one email in order to achieve that

Comment: "https://appname.page.link/email" is the dynamic link url I specified in the Firebase console. email is just an arbitrary name here.

Answer (score 0):

If coming to this answer in March 2022, this error is happening again and it's a bug on Flutterfire.

[Here is the issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/8261) with a Pull Request that hasn't been merged yet.